# Searching using the Google custom search API and displaying links

Tags: c#, api, search

I am working on a personal assistant for home automation and so far it has basic features such as searching wolfram alpha and pulling weather conditions/forecasts but I wan't to enable it to search for things on google and display the results on screen.

After searching around the community it seems the recommended way is to use the Google Search API (which has been replaced with Google Custom Search API. So I have looked at some examples and am able to get the data out into a data grid on the windows form however. I want to show clickable links. How can I do this? I already have an API key and CX to use with the code but cannot get the proper output.

```
GoogleSearch search = new GoogleSearch()
        {
            Key = "KEY HERE",
            CX = "CX HERE"
        };
        search.SearchCompleted += (a, b) =>
        {
            this.DataGridResults.ItemsSource = b.Response.Items;
        };
        search.Search(search_query.Text);
```

Comment: How about Regex to generate clickable links? If that is the only issue.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to get the individual information out of the data grid either so that is my main problem I guess. Though I'm sure there is a much easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this problem after working on it for a long time. Turns out I was just using the list the method returned wrong. I attached a link to the original post that gave me the method and my completed solution which just outputs the titles and HTML links in a text box. You can do whatever you like with them from there.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GoogleSearch search = new GoogleSearch()
        {
            Key = "API KEY HERE",
            CX = "CX GOES HERE"
        };
        search.SearchCompleted += (a, b) =>
        {
            foreach (Item i in b.Response.Items)
            {
                results_box.Text = results_box.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Page Title: " + i.Title;
                results_box.Text = results_box.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Link to Page " + i.Link;

            };
        };
        search.Search(search_query.Text);
```

The method and original post can be found at http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2011/03/google-custom-search-in-c.html